# spring-cloud-netflix: Cannot enable eureka client?

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

Hey I was working on a project where I was trying to register eureka client on server, I got the server enabled easily but somehow cannot get the client to enable I added all the dependencies needed also. I will also include my pom.xml file here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mslab</groupId>
    <artifactId>movie_service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>movie_service</name>
    <description>Movie Service </description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.0-RC2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>netflix-candidates</id>
            <name>Netflix Candidates</name>
            <url>https://artifactory-oss.prod.netflix.net/artifactory/maven-oss-candidates</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

[image: I am getting error like this]

I have used most of the techniques that were available on some previous similar questions but I cannot resolve this issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You dont need to add the annotation to make the service a eureka client.

@EnableEurekaClient annotation is not available in the following spring cloud version

<spring-cloud.version>2022.0.0-RC2</spring-cloud.version>

if you really want to add annotation, you can use @EnableDiscoveryClient

Comment: But the service was not registering in the server without adding the annotation.
I later changed the spring boot to 2.7.6 and then it worked. But still thank you for replying.

Comment: I checked the documentation, but didn't found @EnableDiscoveryClient (mention Link), tested it and worked but also you don't add it and work fine (Eureka 4.0.0).

Answer (score 6):

Eureka version `4.0.0` onwards, which is being used in Spring Cloud `2022.0.0`, you do not need to explicitly register using the annotation `@EnableEurekaClient` It automatically gets registered as client if spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client is on the class path.
As per the -
[documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/docs/current/reference/html/#registering-with-eureka)

> By having spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client on the classpath,
> your application automatically registers with the Eureka Server.
> Configuration is required to locate the Eureka server